# Initialisation of array of collections not working with for each loop

Tags: java, collections, foreach

I have an array of four stacks. And I am initializing it using foreach loop.

```
Stack s[]=new Stack[4];

for(Stack n:s)
{
    n=new Stack();   
}   

System.out.println(s[0]);
```

But the problem with this is it prints null. But when I replaced this with normal for loop

```
Stack s[]=new Stack[4];

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    s[i]=new Stack();   
}       

System.out.println(s[0]);
```

it prints []. I tried it with other java collections LinkedList,ArrayList etc but all are having same behaviour. My question is why the first method is not working, it used to work everywhere ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
for(Stack n:s)
{
    n = new Stack();   
}
```

`n` is a local variable that refers to the current array element while the current value is `null`.
But as you assign a new object to `n` (`new Stack()`), `n` doesn't reference any longer the array element but the new created object.
**The new created object is finally discarded at each iteration and the current array element stays `null`.**

---

This foreach code on an array :

```
for(Stack n : s){
    n = new Stack();   
}
```

could be translated into this code by the compiler :

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    Stack n = s[i]; // the array element is stored in a local variable
    n = new Stack(); // the n local variable refers to a new Stack object
                     // but is not assigned to s[i]
}
```

---

While when you use this syntax :

```
s[i]=new Stack();
```

you explicitly assign the new created object to the `i` element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to populate your array.

```
    Stack s[]=new Stack[4];
    Arrays.setAll(s, i -> new Stack()); 
    System.out.println(s[0]);
```